# How to create object on regular basis with Django?

Tags: django, cron

I'm looking for a way to create a new object based on a model e.g. each month. So as an example having this:

```
from django.db import models

class Monthoverview(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    startdate= models.DateField()
```

And now I want to create, kind like a cron job, for each month a new entry.

How could this be done?

Comment: You have celery for heavy lifting or you can create an admin command and run it from your cron / scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

A pythonic way is to install celery and use celerybeat http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html
You can specify to run your task every month.